# Why does this 3D curve in R show a clear maximum for sigma^2 but not for mu?

Tags: r, 3d, curve, mle, natural-logarithm

So I used the rgl package and created my own likelihood function to output the log likelihood of a sample from a normal distribution. I was doing this really just to learn how to program this myself so I could better understand how likelihood works and also how MLE works. Anyways, I noticed something particularly strange and I wanted to know if someone knew the answer here. When I plot the graph, it comes out in a folded curve shape, but I supposed I was expecting more of a cone type shape. Basically, what im curious about is why when the plot peaks at the sigma^2 value (on this axis, there is a good decline on both sides of the peak), the mu value stays roughly the same? It's as if once the sigma^2 parameter has reached the optimal level, the differences in likelihood between mu values are pretty small. For example, when I check the variance of the likelihoods of the maximum point of sigma (keeping it constant), it's 11.5. In contrast, when I check the variance of the mu's across that same point, the variance is 23402. Since I can't yet post images since I don't have enough reputation, I will just post my R-code that produces the graph.

```
#Define LL function
LL <- function(X, theta)
{
  mu <- theta[1]
  sigma2 <- theta[2]
  log.likelihood <- 0
  n <- length(X)
  for (i in 1:length(X))
  {
      log.likelihood <- log.likelihood - (((X[i]-mu)^2)/(2*sigma2)) - 

log(sqrt(2*pi*sigma2))
  }

  return(log.likelihood)
}

#Parameters
Mu <- 100
Sigma2 <- 50

#Sample
N <- 100
set.seed(1)
IQs <- rnorm(N, mean=Mu, sd=sqrt(Sigma2))

#Possible values to test
x <- posMu <- seq(80, 120, length.out=200)
y <- posSig <- seq(20, 60, length.out=200)
#x1 <- sort(x, decreasing=T)


#Produce LLs for plotting
LLlist <- NULL
for (m in 1:length(posMu)){
  LLs <- NULL
  for(s in 1:length(posSig)){
    posTheta <- cbind(posMu[m],posSig[s])
    LLs <- c(LLs, LL(IQs,posTheta)) 
  }
  LLlist <- cbind(LLlist,LLs, deparse.level=0)
}
z <- LLlist

#Find the approximate MLE 
mLL <- which(LLlist == max(LLlist), arr.ind=TRUE)
cbind(posMu[mLL[2]],posSig[mLL[1]],LLlist[mLL])

#Graph the LLs
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(mean(x),mean(y),mean(z), xlab="Mu", ylab="Sigma2", zlab="log L", xlim=c(min(x),max(x)), ylim=c(min(y),max(y)), zlim=c(min(z),max(z)))
surface3d(x, y, z, color=rainbow(length(x)))
```

So, is my code just wrong? Or is this what a LL curve should look like? If so, why is it that sigma^2 seems to show a clear curve and height whereas mu hardly differs at the maximum? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A general comment: keep in  mind that the mean and variance of a given distribution are orthogonal, which means that there's no functional relationship between the two.  Consider the mean and sigma of the pair `-x,x` .  The mean is always zero but as `x` increases in magnitude, so does  sigma.  Alternatively, the data set `x,x,x,x,x` has a mean value `x` but sigma is always zero.

Comment: Right, so would that mean that there is something wrong with my code? It seems like the graph implies that the likelihood of the mean value depends on the variance value, but not vice versa.